# Why does this program give me a miscalculation only on the first input?

Tags: c, temperature

This is my attempt at using a function to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius in C. What has me puzzled is that it works for every input except the first one and I can't figure out why. If I remove the while loop and just leave whats inside the program works as expected but then I can only convert one value before having to run the program again.The first value entered is usually -16. something for me.

As a side note can anyone recommend a method to search for these types of questions when its kind of program specific?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    float fToC(float far);

    int main()
    {
        int c;
        float far;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
        scanf("%f", &far);
        printf("%.2f\n", fToC(far));
        }
        return 0;
     }

    float fToC(float far)
    {
        float C;
        C = (5.0 / 9.0) * (far - 32.0);
        return C;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `getchar` does? What do you do with the value it returns to you?

Comment: `getchar` reads one character from the input. On the first entry, `getchar` "gobbles up" the first digit you enter, so it reads the first number wrong. For example, if you first enter "54" it will read the 5, dispose of it, and convert 4 to Celsius. Subsequent `getchar` calls read the carrage return or line feed, leaving the following numbers intact. Try pressing Enter first before entering any numbers. Or put a space before the first digit you enter on the first number. You'll see these will make it work.

Comment: @lurker Thanks a lot I get it now. If you posted that as an answer I would have picked it for the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getchar() eats the first character and scanf() can't read it. Starting on the second iteration this is ok: the eaten character will be '\n', then ENTER key that scanf() does not read. On the first time, however, the character is an useful one: '-' when "-16" is typed. Solution: remove the getchar() and use a scanf parse format that skips white space: " %f".

Answer (score 3):

Is there a need for getchar()?  Newline character (invisible character) is also
considered as an input. It stays in the input buffer and gets assigned to `far`.

Skip getchar() and just enter `far`.
scanf() returns 1 if appropriate input has entered.
If an inappropriate input has entered like a letter, it will return 0 and simply wont go inside the loop.

```
    while((scanf("%f", &far) == 1))
    {
       printf( "far = %f\n", far);
       printf("%.2f\n", fToC(far));
    }
```